# Is IDataErrorInfo a waste of memory?

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I have a list of business objects (1000+) with 50 or so properties they have around 70 different validations that need to be performed. It seems like the way to go is to use a validation rule, but I really like `IDataErrorInfo`. Is it a waste of memory to have `IDataErrorInfo` defined for every object while they use the same validation all along?

PS: I didn't post the code because it enormous and tedious to look at.

Comment: Have you experienced performance problems?

Comment: Not yet, just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDataErrorInfo` just contains a pair of properties.
It has no per-instance overhead.

It's up to you to make an implementation that peforms well; the shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I thought I might bloat the size of objects with the error messages, regular expressions and all other stuff I need. Even though all the objects use the same exact logic. I guess making sure the implementation performs well implies making everything I need for validation static?

Comment: @Wallace: Store regexes and error message strings in `static readonly` and `const` fields

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of extending the built in ValidationRule class and using it directly in bindings, as opposed to using IDataErrorInfo.

Check my blog post here, see if it helps: [Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level - part 1](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html). This concentrates on how to use it for validating a TextBox, but the exact same thing applies to any bindable element, i.e. columns on a DataGrid. The advantages it gives you is you can keep the validation code out of your viewmodel and model (if you are using that sort of pattern), the validation is reusable anywhere, and you can be quite granular with which validations are applied and where.

Comment: When Model or ViewModel objects get complex, it can really help ito maintainability to move validation out to a separate class - so I like this answer! May want to reconsider how effectively it answers the original question though?